# After effects effects name

Tags: animation, after-effects

I want to know what effects is added to this video (https://in.pinterest.com/pin/871657702858299499/) in After effects software

Answer (score 0):

Not a question I'd post on Stackoverflow, anyway they probably used [LoopFlow](https://aescripts.com/loopflow/)